# Set insertion into Database

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, set

I am having this error:
Error executing DDL "create table role_permissions (role_id bigint not null, permission varchar(255) check (permission in ()))" via JDBC [ERROR: syntax error at or near ")"
how can i avoid this?

```
package tokhirov.sukhrob.todo.entities;

import jakarta.persistence.ElementCollection;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.EnumType;
import jakarta.persistence.Enumerated;
import lombok.*;
import org.hibernate.annotations.SQLDelete;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Where;
import tokhirov.sukhrob.todo.entities.enums.Permissions;
import tokhirov.sukhrob.todo.entities.template.AbsEntity;

import java.util.Set;

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Where(clause = "deleted=false")
@SQLDelete(sql = "update roles set deleted=true where id=?")
@Entity(name = "roles")
public class Role extends AbsEntity {

    private String name;

    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    @ElementCollection
    private Set<Permissions> permissions;

}
```

Comment: show Permissions class pls !